# stackBuilder.addParentStack is Not Working- Navigate to Main Activity (OnBackPressed)

Tags: android, android-notifications

When user Click on Notification, it will open New Activity That's Working fine. But When i Presss Back button it closed Application

What i want ?
When i click on Back button it return MainActivity(Selected Activity )Everytim.

```
 private void generateNotificationNew(Context context, String message,String pushIdmessage) {

        Intent resultIntent = null;

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText(message);



        resultIntent = new Intent(context,ResultActivity.class);
        //Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, AvailableJobActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        5,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

`stackBuilder.addParentStack` or `stackBuilder.addNextIntent` may not working properly.
Any Alternative option Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For **generate notification** you need to put following code...

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("Notificatin Title")
                .setContentText("message");
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this , ResultActivity);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0 , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify( 0 , builder.build());
```

And for the handle back event you need to check following things in **onBackPressed()** in **Result Activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(this.isTaskRoot())
        startActivity(new Intent(this , MainActivity.class));
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Now you can redirect to MainActivity from notification started activity..
**Enjoy it**...:-)